# How do I return the result of two queries below each other

Tags: sql, excel, select, odbc, firebird

I have the following query:

```
SELECT GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME
FROM GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS 
WHERE GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT = '61111'
```

That returns the following result:

[image]

I then want to add another field below it, also from a query. So I did the following;

```
SELECT
   GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME,
   (SELECT GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME 
    FROM GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS
    WHERE GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT = '71111')
FROM
   GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS
WHERE
   GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT = '61111'
```

That then returns the following:

[image]

I actually want the Food COS to appear below Room Revenue field. Is there a way to do this:

[image]

I know my query does not really make sense as I can easily include the result as part of the query. But I need to understand the basic principle of adding data below each other in the same query as I need to use this to put a much bigger report together.

Comment: Do you really want the "`ACCOUNT_NAME2`" in an individual row?

Comment: Yes. I know it looks a little bizarre but it forms part of a bigger report where I will require this.

Comment: hardcode it!!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is UNION.
With UNION you can add multiple querys together as long as they have the same columns.

```
SELECT GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME FROM GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS WHERE GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT = '61111'

UNION

SELECT GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME FROM GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS WHERE GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT = '71111'
```

EDIT:
The aditional Header Row you can add as "nikhil sugandh" suggested, "hardcoded"

```
SELECT GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME FROM GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS WHERE GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT = '61111'

UNION

SELECT 'ACCOUNT_NAME_2' AS ACCOUNT_NAME

UNION

SELECT GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME FROM GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS WHERE GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT = '71111'
```

Comment: Thank you, that solved my problem. I suspected that it is a job for UNION but I kept trying to include brackets. Perfect.
How would I go about it if I wanted a blank space between the results?

Comment: The union here is redundant as it is equivalent to a simple select:
`SELECT GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT_NAME FROM GLACCOUNTS GLACCOUNTS WHERE GLACCOUNTS.ACCOUNT IN ('61111','71111')`.
Didn't you wanted a multiple headers in rows, like stated in the example?

Comment: @RaulSebastian yes you are right this particular one could be done with the IN, but since mentioned he needs it for a bigger report the IN might not be as straight forward as the UNION.

Comment: Right, his question was not clear, if you take a look at the example there is an ACCOUNT_NAME2 row, which suggests he wants headers in rows. This would perfectly work using UNION but results are not guaranteed to be ordered without an ORDER BY, meaning he would need an additional column for sorting.

Comment: @gdekoker however you have to account for difference between `UNION ALL` and `UNION DISTINCT` and choose which one you need